# Programmatically creating SVG with Phaser 3: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'texture')

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

The goal is to let user edit a SVG that's the source texture for a predefined set of animations. For some reason the animation doesn't play, it's always stuck at the first frame, and when I call `play()` explicitly, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'texture')
    at AnimationState.setCurrentFrame (phaser.js:43946:1)
    at AnimationState.handleStart (phaser.js:43412:1)
    at AnimationState.update (phaser.js:43888:1)
    at Sprite.preUpdate (phaser.js:19644:1)
    at UpdateList.sceneUpdate (phaser.js:168672:1)
    at EventEmitter.emit (phaser.js:1928:1)
    at Systems.step (phaser.js:49066:1)
    at SceneManager.update (phaser.js:100289:1)
    at Game.step (phaser.js:162805:1)
    at TimeStep.step (phaser.js:89366:1)
```

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```js
const atlasJson =  this.cache.json.get('atlas-json');
const animationJson = this.cache.json.get('animation-json');
image.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    documentUrl.revokeObjectURL(svgBlobUrl);
    const texture = this.textures.addAtlas('atlas', image, atlasJson);
    const sprite = this.add.sprite(100, 100, texture);
    sprite.play('do_stuff'); // throws undefined properties error
}
```

Debugging tells me `animationFrame.frame` is undefined. And the animation index is at 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the atlas data structure. I should have been calling `addAtlasJSONHash()` instead of `addAtlas()`.